# Precision of floats with printf

Tags: c, floating-point, printf, precision

As everybody knows, you have limited precision when you use `printf` to output the value of a `float`.
However, there is a trick to increase the accuracy in the output, as this example shows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float f = 1318926965;        /* 10 random digits */
    printf("%10.f\n", f);        /* prints only 8 correct digits */
    printf("%10d\n", *(int*)&f); /* prints all digits correctly */
    return 0;
}
```

and my question is, why don't people use this trick more often?

Comment: Because potentially undefined behavior is bad.  (Edit:  Technically it may not be undefined behavior, as I'm not sure what the standard says about it.  Endianess could bite you with this though.)

Comment: +1 for a good April's 1st joke!

Comment: It apparently got me x.x

Comment: You should have used an union for an irreproachable April's fool joke.

Comment: Or some macro that makes it totally unclear what I'm doing? No, I didn't want to obfuscate my program. Sometimes it's best to hide things out in the open.

Comment: @MrLister I'm not saying that your program is too readable, I am saying that it is too undefined. Look up "strict aliasing rules" tomorrow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

April fool?

Your "random number" `1318926965` have the same underlying representation both in decimal and floating-point form.

Try another value, like `10`. It will print as:

```
        10
1092616192
```

So to answer your question:

```
and my question is, why don't people use this trick more often?
```

Because only one day of the year is April Fools Day... The rest of the days the trick doesn't work...

Answer (score 4):

Try that same trick with a different number, say 2318926965.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float f = 2318926965;        /* 10 random digits */
    printf("%10.f\n", f);        /* prints only 8 correct digits */
    printf("%10d\n", *(int*)&f); /* prints all digits correctly */
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -O3  t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:7:5: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
$ ./a.out 
2318926848
1326069764
```

I don't see an increase in precision at all with your "trick" that depends on the bit representation of floats on your platform (as far as I understand it).

[This thread](http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=64223) has a few other of these "magic floats" and a way to generate them.

Comment: It depends on the bit representation of floats per IEEE 754, not "on your platform". (Modulo possible byte order issues that don't exist on any real-world machines.) IMO the only thing bad about code like this is the improper type-punning which should be replaced with unions (sketchy but intentionally supported by all compilers) or `memcpy` (100% legal C).

Comment: If IEEE 754 is mandatory, what's the use for the `__STDC_IEC_559__` define?

Comment: It's not mandatory, but considering how broken the C standard allows non-IEEE-conformant implementations' floating point to be, and that there's no other way you can tell what you can rely on in regards to floating point arithmetic, I would consider it a huge mistake for programs that want to be portable to non-IEEE-math systems to use floating point whatsoever. (Naturally however you could use it on a non-portable program intended only for use on a single non-IEEE-math implementation.)

Answer (score 0):

The limit to precision is with the floating point representation, not with `printf()`  it is a false premise.

Moreover a single precision float is only guaranteed correct to 6 digits of precision, so the "trick" would be fooling yourself; in the general case it would not work.

If you want 10 digit floating-point numbers then you should use double precision, which is good for 15 digits.